# How to find eigenfunctions of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, integral-equations

I wonder if there is a general way of finding characteristic values and eigenfunctions of a given linear operator described by an integral.

As a special case suppose I am interested in this function:
$$g(x,t)=\min((1-x)t,(1-t)x), 0<x<1, 0<t<1$$ and I want to find $\lambda_i$ and $y_i(x)$ such that

$$y_i(x)-\lambda_i\int_0^1g(x,t)y_i(t)dt=0.$$

How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be interested in $\int_0^1 g(x,t) y_i(t) \, dt = \lambda_i y_i(x)$? (I'm writing this in the form $Ax = \lambda x$ that you can recall from linear algebra.)

Comment: I just edited your question to attract readers more precisely ; you're trying to find eigenfunctions of a linear operator $L[y](x) = \int_0^1 g(x,t) y(t) \, dt$.

Comment: @Patrik, obviously the two definitions are closely related to each other. Thanks for editing the question.

Comment: Note $g(x,t)=\min\{t,x\}-tx$.

Comment: This is a kernel connected with brownian bridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We find 
$$y(x) = \lambda \left[ (1-x)\int_0^x dt\, t y(t) + x\int_x^1 (1-t) y(t)\right].$$
This has a form similar to a Volterra equation of the first kind. 
A standard technique is to take derivatives, thus transforming the integral equation into a differential equation. 
Taking the second derivative of both sides with respect to $x$ we find 
$$y'' = -\lambda y.$$
Thus, the solutions should be of the form 
$$y = A \sin\sqrt{\lambda} x + B \cos\sqrt{\lambda} x.$$
Plugging this back into the original integral equation we find $B = 0$ and $\lambda = n^2 \pi^2$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Thus, the solutions are of the form 
$$y = A \sin n \pi x$$
with eigenvalues 
$$\lambda = n^2 \pi^2.$$

*Addendum*. 
Another possible solution to the differential equation that we ignored above is $\lambda=0$ and $y = A+ B t$. 
However, this is not compatible with the integral equation unless $A = B = 0$. 
Notice also that hyperbolic solutions have been ruled out. 
Initially we just assumed $\lambda$ was some complex number. 
The integral equation then told us that $\lambda$ is real.

Comment: @ oenamen: Many thanks indeed for your wonderful solution. May I ask a follow up question. Suppose we change minimum to maximum in the definition of $g(x,t)$. Of course one can follow your solution to find the new eigenfunctions. I wonder if there is a smart way to use the relationship that $$\min(x,t)=-\max(-x,-t)$$ and fins eigenfunctions for $$g(x,t)=\max((1-x)t,(1-t)x)$$?

Comment: @MikaelAnderson: You're very welcome. I don't see a way to use these solutions to get those for your new $g$. Perhaps someone else does.

Comment: For the new $g$ function as above I followed oenamen's solution and after taking the second derivative I find $$y′′=λy.$$ If I understand correctly, the solution to this is of the form $$y=c_1\exp(x\sqrt(\lambda)+c_2\exp(-x\sqrt(\lambda).$$ I do not seem to be able to find a simple answer for $c_1,c_2$ though. I wonder if anyone can see how I can continue to find eigenfunctions as in oenamen's solution for the new $g$.

Comment: @MikaelAnderson: There is one solution, $y = A\left(\sqrt{\lambda} \cosh\sqrt{\lambda}x - \sinh \sqrt{\lambda}x\right)$ for $\lambda$ a solution to $\tanh\sqrt\lambda = 2\sqrt\lambda/(1+\lambda)$. Numerically, $\lambda = 2.382\cdots$. This can be most easily seen by relating the integral equation to a differential equation with Robin boundary conditions. There are too many details for a comment. Perhaps you should ask another question!

Comment: @MikaelAnderson: Keep in mind that the integral equation imposes boundary conditions, they are built-in. If you change the kernel you also change the boundary conditions. For example, they may become very restrictive, as you have noticed above.

Comment: @ oenamen: Thanks. I asked a follow-up question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132531/24484).