# Is there some operator generator of an analytical semigroup with eigenvalues such that $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{|\lambda_k|} < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, laplacian, semigroup-of-operators

The following is pretty relevant for my research:

Consider the Laplacian $\Delta$ in 1-D then under certain conditions it is well known that it is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are $\lambda_k=-k^2$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $$\sum_{k} \frac{1}{|\lambda_k|} < \infty$$
Note that the series doesn't converge in dimension $d=2,3$ as $\lambda_k =-k^{2/d}$.

Now (except for the Laplacian in 1-D) is there some other linear operator a generator of an analytical semigroup which is diagonalizable with
eigenvalues $\lambda_k$  such that satisfy
$$\sum_{k} \frac{1}{|\lambda_k|} < \infty ?$$

Comment: You may be inspired by this example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132273

Comment: Are $\lambda_i$ or $-\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues ? (if it is the second case, it looks me ambiguous).

Comment: they are $\lambda_i \leq 0$ as for the Laplacian they are $\lambda_i=-i^2$

Comment: the condition $$\sum_{k} \frac{1}{-\lambda_k} < \infty ?$$ is to have a positive series.

Comment: Yes in that example it is calculating the eigenvalues of the laplacian which are the oness I was mentioning. I was wondering if there is some other operator satisfying the condition

Comment: in this case, notation $< \infty$ is to be reconsidered...

Comment: I don't understand the issue about having all negative eigenvalues : if you know an operator with all positive eigenvalues, it suffices to take its opposite...

Comment: Yes of course that doesn't matter, the important thing is the convergence of the series of $|\lambda_i|$

Comment: I corrected so it is better

Comment: A half-baked idea is to look at perturbations of the Laplacian. It's easy to satisfy your summability condition, but i confess i don't know much about analytic semi-groups (as opposed to just strongly continuous).

Comment: See an answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528378) using a "laplacian" for the computation of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x_i^2}=\dfrac{1}{10}$ where the $x_i$ are the $>0$ roots of equation $x=\tan x$.

Comment: Yes thanks, for the Laplacian is clear, what about the square of the Laplacian $\Delta^2$ in 2-D. Its eigenvalues satisfy the summability condition. But does it generate an analytical semigroup?

Comment: @carlos85 Yes, the bi-laplacian under similar conditions generates an analytic semigroup.

Comment: @S.Maths so also the $p$-Laplacian in dimension $p$? Where can I find references for the analiticity of the semigroup generated by the $p$-Laplacian because I'm having troubles finding it?

Comment: @carlos $p$-Laplacian is used for an other (nonlinear) operator ..